# Where svn store project code?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I spent all day installing the svn server on my virtual debian 7. So now I have working svn server on `svn://` and `http://` protocols. With the `http://` I haven't got any problems, but with the `svn://` first I couldn't create a project folder in my repo through Tortoise browser, there was some error: "User cancelled", after this I did it in the console with some command like this one

`svn mkdir -m "project folder" svn://svn.host/repo/project`

then a message for root password appeared, next svn user name and pass, and the project folder showed up to the Tortoise browser. I did 3 folders trough Tortoise browser: trunk, branches and tags, and I added my local project to the trunk directory. So now everything seems to work fine just when access my repo through console, ftp or http I can see the trunk branches and tags directories. I tried to find them in the linux tree with no success, it is very strange because the project is there in the Tortoise Browser, but not in the repo. Thanks of any good people which can help me to understand whats going on, and sorry for the level of my English still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subversion repository is basically a database; you won't see the literal names of files and directories if you inspect it directly. This follows from the purpose of subversion: to store the history of every file and folder, including its state at every past revision, and metadata such as log messages, and actions which change the directory structure, such as renames and deletes.

Laying out the repository the same way as the code being stored would be a very inefficient solution for this aim.